# How to make a new line in the source file but not the output

Tags: sourcecode

I want to adhere to the traditional '80 character' line length limit in my `.tex` source file.

How do I do a new line in the source but not in the document output?

Comment: A new line in the input counts as a space in the output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the TeXbook, p. 25

> And now comes the good news, if you haven't used computer typesetting
>   before:  You don't have to worry about where to break lines in a paragraph
>   (i.e., where to stop at the right margin and to begin a new line), because
>   TeX will do that for you. Your manuscript file can contain long lines or
>   short lines, or both; it doesn't matter. This is especially helpful when
>   you make changes, since you don't have to retype anything except the words
>   that changed. *Every time you begin a new line in your manuscript file
>   it is essentially the same as typing a space.* When TeX has read an
>   entire paragraph—in this case lines 7 to 11—it will try to break up
>   the text so that each line of output, except the last, contains about the
>   same amount of copy; and it will hyphenate words if necessary to keep the
>   spacing consistent, but only as a last resort.

Remember also that spaces are ignored at the start of a line and that a sequence of spaces is equivalent to one. However, a blank line will count as an end of paragraph command.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to use linebreaks wisely: Indent your LaTeX source for readability,
split lines at punctuation or into phrases. That way most changes involve shuffling lines around, which is easier than snipping and pasting between lines.